# Showing an inequality with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to show that $0<\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}xsin(\sqrt[3]{4x^2})dx\leq 1$.

For the right inequality, since $xsin(\sqrt[3]{4x^2})\leq x$ so by monowe have $\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}xsin(\sqrt[3]{4x^2})\leq \int_{0}^{\sqrt2}x=[x^2/2]_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt2}=1$.
For the other side, is it fine to say that $f(x)=xsin(\sqrt[3]{4x^2})\geq 0$ in $[0,\sqrt2]$ and (for example) in $x=1\in [0,\sqrt2]$, $f(1)>0$ so $\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}xsin(\sqrt[3]{4x^2})>0$?

Comment: It's pedantic but I would simply note that the last implication follows from $f$ being continuous, but this looks fine.

Comment: Note that the absolute value of the sine function is bounded by $1$.   Hence, the integrand is bounded by $|x|$.  And $\int_0^{\sqrt 2}|x|\,dx=1$.  For the left-hand side inequaltiy, note that $\sin(2)>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine, but you have to mention the reason why this implies so.
The answer is in the continuity of the function. In fact, it is not sufficient for it to be $>0$ in a point in order to have a positive integral. Continuity is fundamental here.

If you want to formally justify it you can just say that since $f(1)>0$ and $1$ is an internal point of the interval $[0,\sqrt 2]$, by continuity it exists an interval $[1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon] \subset [0,\sqrt 2]$, with $\varepsilon>0$, where $f\geq \frac{f(1)}{2}$ and so the integral will be $\geq$ than $(1+\varepsilon - (1-\varepsilon))\cdot \frac{f(1)}{2}=f(1)\cdot \varepsilon>0$.